# how to Paragraph text come display like text typing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to display text come with typing text effect.i tried like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="holder"></span>

</body>
<script>
(function($) 
 {
    $.fn.writeText = function(content) {
        var contentArray = content.split(""),
            current = 0,
            elem = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            if(current < contentArray.length) {
                elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
            }
        }, 100);
    };

})(jQuery);
$("#holder").writeText("This is some text");

</script>
</html>
```

It's work but i need display Paragraph content like this but now to call Paragraph content in writeText.

If it's not good way to display Pragraph

like typing effect. Please tell me how to solved my problem .Please give me any idea.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/#q=stack+overflow+typewriter+effect

Comment: There are many js libraries available to achieve this effect. Eg typed.js, shabdawali, itype etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have simply modified your code for this, you just need get the content of each para and pass each para to your writeText function()

Just give class="effect" to

to be animated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="holder"></span>
<p class="effect">Hi, this is Gokul Praveen' PARA 1!</p>
<p class="effect">Hi, this is James Bond's PARA 2!</p>
</body>
<script>
(function($) 
 {
    $.fn.writeText = function(content) {
        var contentArray = content.split(""),
            current = 0,
            elem = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            if(current < contentArray.length) {
                elem.text(elem.text() + contentArray[current++]);
            }
        }, 100);
    };

})(jQuery);

$(".effect").each(function(index) {
    var text = $( this ).text();
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).writeText(text);
});
//$("#holder").writeText("This is some text");

</script>
</html>
```

Execute the code in a browser and check. Don't forget to mark it correct!

Answer (score 0):

I think this fiddle will do the trick

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/RED9H/116/)

```
$.fn.typer = function (text, options) {
        options = $.extend({}, {
            char: ' ',
            delay: 1000,
            duration: 600,
            endless: true
        }, options || text);

        text = $.isPlainObject(text) ? options.text : text;

        var elem = $(this),
            isTag = false,
            c = 0;

        (function typetext(i) {
            var e = ({
                string: 1,
                number: 1
            }[typeof text] ? text : text[i]) + options.char,
                char = e.substr(c++, 1);

            if (char === '<') {
                isTag = true;
            }
            if (char === '>') {
                isTag = false;
            }
            elem.html(e.substr(0, c));
            if (c <= e.length) {
                if (isTag) {
                    typetext(i);
                } else {
                    setTimeout(typetext, options.duration / 10, i);
                }
            } else {
                c = 0;
                i++;

                if (i === text.length && !options.endless) {
                    return;
                } else if (i === text.length) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                setTimeout(typetext, options.delay, i);
            }
        })(0);
    };

    $('#foo').typer(['<i>Anyone</i> <u>is</u> <b>awesome</b>!', 'Foo bar.', 1337]);
```

Comment: thanks for reply But i need Paragraph content I placed in html like this <p>some text</p>.if help me if know about how to display some text with typing effect